# Qt GUIアプリケーションの作成方法について

Tags: c++, qt

QtCreatorを使用しての、GUIアプリケーションの作成方法についてお教えいただけないでしょうか。

Qtでメモ帳を作成するために、Qt GUIアプリケーションプロジェクトを利用したいのですが、
プロジェクトの新規作成の一覧に、そのような名前のプロジェクトが無く、困っております。
メモ帳の作成には、`<QTextEdit>`をincludeする必要があると思うのですが、
どのプロジェクトでも、includeすることができず悩んでおります。

何か、インストールが足りないのでしょうか？
もしくは現在のQtcreatorのバージョンでは、別のプロジェクト名に変わっているのでしょうか？

回答を宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

.proファイルの変数「QT」に「widgets」の記述を追記すれば`<QTextEdit>`のincludeが可能になると思います。

記述例

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Comment: お教えいただいた方法で使用することができました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

足りないものを尋ねるのであれば、まず何をインストールしたのか提示すべきです。

とりあえず手元のQt 5.7.1 + Qt Creator 4.2.0ではQt Widgets Applicationプロジェクトを選択でき、`QTextEdit`を使用できました。

Comment: 次回の質問では気を付けるようにいたします。ありがとうございました。

Comment: @ゾマホン さん「次回」ではなく今回のバージョンを教えてください。Qt 5.7.1 + Qt Creator 4.2.0では別回答で指摘されている設定は初めから書かれており特に書き換える必要はありません。また「そのような名前のプロジェクトが無く」の問題がどう解決したのかも謎なままです。